# Livewire 'wire:poll' conflicting with the 'logout' functionality

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, laravel-10, laravel-livewire-wireclick

Whenever I add the 'wire:poll.250ms' to update a table automatically, and try to logout of the website dashboard I get an 419 page expired error.

I tried adding the logout button in a livewire component and adding 'wire:ignore' to the root  and also removing the @csrf directives from the code. I've also tried to exclude the logout from the 'VerifyCsrdToken.php' middelwear file. All with no luck at all. I am using the TALL (tailwind, alpine, laravel, livewire) stack. I am a newbie at livewire so any advice would be great!

Comment: Removing CSRF is a bad idea. It's hard to help without seeing your actual code.